# Using Weave's Kubenetes YAML file, how can I ensure that Weave uses the local interface?

Tags: interface, kubernetes, lan, weave

I try to install Kubernetes with `﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠kubeadm`﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠.  Moreover, I install a pod network with

```
kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube
```

as recommended on http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/addons/ when you click on “Weave Net”.  It works, but I have two interface cards per node: One to the Internet and one for the LAN between all nodes.  How can I assure that Weave uses the interface to the LAN?

Comment: seems like the key here is the use of CNI. 
this may help. You probably need to dig into the kube-up script to figure where the CNI stuff is setup and verify it is using the right interface.
https://github.com/containernetworking/cni

Comment: FWIW, I received this comment on the Weave mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/weave.works/forum/#!topic/weave-users/-JWHW_jAXNM

Comment: Sounds good. You should probably put that as the answer for others to see here. Unless you want me to. Cheers

Comment: I first test it.  I haven't had time to do so yet.

Comment: @TorstenBronger, would you have any update on this? Did you eventually get it to work?

Comment: @MarcCarré I appended an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each node, the own `/etc/hostname` should resolve to an *internal* IP through an entry in `/etc/hosts`.  This way, Kubernetes uses the internal network for inter-node communication by default.